# HTML Signature in Gmail using media queries for show/hide container?

Tags: html, gmail, media-queries

Based from my research, Gmail and other email clients doesn't support media queries so I can't do simple conditional show and hide of a container.

I have 2 designs. One is for the desktop email signature and the other one is for mobile devices. Are there any other ways on how to implement responsive HTML email signatures in Gmail browser/mobile app?

Thanks.

Comment: If your email signature is so complex it needs media queries, I'd encourage you to just **ditch your email signature**.

Comment: How much code are you trying to put in a signature?

Comment: I was tasked by my Boss to create responsive HTML signature. My media query is just for showing and hiding the desktop or mobile design. I already informed him about this Gmail limitation and just waiting for his response. For the meantime there might be a solution or no solution at all for gmail. Thanks

Comment: @mlegg not too much. How can I do simple show and hide other than using media queries?

Comment: @marknt15 It's HTML email. It's a miracle when anything post-1990s technology works at all in HTML email. To my knowledge, there is no workaround here - your boss has given you an impossible task.